# Optimising a Deep Learning Model Running Slow on Kaggle

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, genetic-algorithm, kaggle

I am running a deep learning model on Kaggle, and it is running extremely slow. The code is used for training a GRU model with Genetic Algorithm (using the DEAP library) to optimise hyperparameters.

I am using the GPU setting in kaggle

This method has worked for me before when testing other hyperparameters. With the new ones it has changed.

I previously tested for the following parameters:

- gru_units
- learning_rate
- epochs
- batch_size

This time, I am testing for:

- learning_rate
- epochs
- activation_function in the GRU layers
- optimizer used

Here's the code snippet:

import libraries

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import GRU, Dropout, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop, Adagrad, SGD
from deap import creator, base, tools, algorithms
```

pre-process data

```py
df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/nvda-with-indicators/hist-indicator-nvda.csv', index_col='time', parse_dates=True)

# Select the features you want to use
features = ['high', 'low', 'close', 'Volume MA', 'EMA', 'Accumulation/Distribution', 'EOM', 'ATR', 'MOM', '%K', '%D', 'RSI', 'APO']
df = df[features]

# Scale the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(df)

scaler_pred = MinMaxScaler()
df_Close = pd.DataFrame(df['close'])
np_Close_scaled = scaler_pred.fit_transform(df_Close)

window_size = 50
look_ahead = 2

# Create a sliding window for input features
def create_dataset(data, window_size=1, look_ahead=look_ahead):
    X, y = [], []
    for i in range(len(data) - window_size - look_ahead + 1):
        X.append(data[i:(i + window_size), :])
        y.append(data[i + window_size + look_ahead - 1, 2]) # 'close' column index is 2
    return np.array(X), np.array(y).reshape(-1, 1)

X, y = create_dataset(scaled_data, window_size, look_ahead)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
train_size = int(len(X) * 0.8)
X_train, X_test = X[:train_size], X[train_size:]
y_train, y_test = y[:train_size], y[train_size:]
```

funciton to create and evaluate individuals

```
def evaluate_individual(individual):
                        
    learning_rate, epochs, activation_function, optimizer_name = individual
    
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(GRU(units=32, return_sequences=True, activation=activation_function, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))

    model.add(GRU(units=32, activation=activation_function))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))

    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))

    if optimizer_name == 'Adam':
        optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    elif optimizer_name == 'RMSprop':
        optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    elif optimizer_name == 'Adagrad':
        optimizer = Adagrad(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    elif optimizer_name == 'SGD':
        optimizer = SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate)

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=int(epochs), batch_size=32, verbose=0)

    loss = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    
    return (loss,)
```

Initialising Genetic Algorithm Components and Hyperparameters

```
creator.create("FitnessMin", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMin)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
# toolbox.register("gru_units", random.choice, [32, 50, 64])
toolbox.register("learning_rate", random.uniform, 1e-4, 1e-2)
toolbox.register("epochs", random.randint, 10, 50)
# toolbox.register("batch_size", random.choice, [32, 64, 128])
toolbox.register("activation_function", random.choice, ['tanh', 'relu', 'elu', 'LeakyReLU'])
toolbox.register("optimizer_name", random.choice, ['Adam', 'RMSprop', 'Adagrad', 'SGD'])

toolbox.register("individual", tools.initCycle, creator.Individual,
                 (toolbox.learning_rate, toolbox.epochs, toolbox.activation_function,
                  toolbox.optimizer_name), n=1)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxTwoPoint)
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutGaussian, mu=0, sigma=1, indpb=0.05)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=4)
toolbox.register("evaluate", evaluate_individual)
```

Running the Genetic Algorithm Optimization and Printing the Best Individual

```
def main():
    random.seed(42)
    pop = toolbox.population(n=10)
    hof = tools.HallOfFame(10)
    stats = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats.register("avg", np.mean)
    stats.register("std", np.std)
    stats.register("min", np.min)
    stats.register("max", np.max)

    pop, log = algorithms.eaMuPlusLambda(pop, toolbox, mu=5, lambda_=5, cxpb=0.6, mutpb=0.2, ngen=10, 
                               stats=stats, halloffame=hof, verbose=True)
    return pop, log, hof

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pop, log, hof = main()
    best_individual_pop = tools.selBest(pop, 1)[0]
    print("Best individual is: %s\nwith fitness: %s" % (best_individual_pop, best_individual_pop.fitness))
    best_individual = hof[0]
    print("Best individual is: %s\nwith fitness: %s" % (best_individual, best_individual.fitness))
```

Any suggestions to do with the problem or the code in general would be hugely appreciated. Thank you